# How can i get looping autocomplete value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My PHP Code In Model using Codeigniter

```
$return_arr =array();
$new_row =array();

foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $new_row['value'] = $row['test_type_name'];
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('p_test');
    $this->db->where('test_type_name',$new_row['value']);
    $query_tt = $this->db->get();
    $i =0;

    foreach($query_tt->result_array() as $row_tt) {
        $i++;
        $new_row['test_name'.$i] = $row_tt['test_name'];
    }
    $new_row['inc_i'] = $i;
    array_push($return_arr,$new_row);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

My jQuery Code

```
$('#p_test_name').keydown(function () { 
   var id_no_t = document.getElementById('id_no').value; 
   $(this).autocomplete({ 
       source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>p_con/p_test_name/" + id_no_t, 
       minLength: 0, 
       autoFocus: true, 
       select: function (event, ui) 
       { 
          var tot_i = ui.item.inc_i;
          for (i = 1; i <= tot_i; i++) 
          { 
              var test_name = 'test_name'+i; 
                  test_name = ui.item.test_name; 
              $("#test_name"+i).val(test_name);
          }
       } 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Actually i want to get value using loop.

If i use separately ui.item.test_name1, ui.item.test_name2 .......etc without loop.

Then Value comes perfect but if i use loop like my above code then value comes undefined.

Please tell me, How to solve it?

Comment: Dou you have check `tot_i`, is it the last `inc_i`'s value? In your model, you have more `inc_i` key value, so I think you can try to use `ui.length`.

Comment: length or tot_i is all right but test_name value do not come. If i use separately test_name = ui.item.test_name1 then test_name value comes properly but when i use loop then it don't come.

Comment: try to use `eval("var test_name = ui.item.test_name");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ui.item.test_name` in which the `test_name` is referred to as the key. If I understand your question correctly, what you are willing to do is to use the value of `test_name` as key. Try this instead:

```
for (i = 1; i <= tot_i; i++) 
{ 
    var test_name = 'test_name' + i; 
        test_name = ui.item[test_name];
    $("#test_name"+i).val(test_name);
}
```

This should effectively turn out to be using `ui.item['test_name1']` or object style notation `ui.item.test_name1`, for every value of `i`.

Also on a side note, you are redeclaring test_name using the `var` keyword. Declaring it once is fine and better for code readability. Only declare vars once.

Comment: It's not working. If i value is 3, if i use ui.item.test_name1, ui.item.test_name2,ui.item.test_name3 then value will come perfect. Since i value is not fixed, so how to get for every i value using loop.(such as ui.item.test_name(1/2/3..))

Comment: Using the code I posted, it first sets the var test_name to the values test_name1, test_name2, etc. 

Next it reassigns the value of test_name to ui.item['test_name1'], ui.item['test_name2'], etc.

That value is then used in the jquery val() function. 

For better debugging, can you do a console.log on ui.item above the for-loop, and a console.log on test_name directly above the jquery val() function? That way we can see exactly what we're working with.